# Question about the proof: the class of subsets of X having the BP is a $\sigma$-algebra, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing open and meager sets

Tags: general-topology

I give two preliminary notions:

> $\mathbf{Def}$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ is the $\sigma$-ideal of meager sets of a  topological space. We write
> $A=^* B$ if $A, B$ are equal modulo meager sets, i.e. $A\triangle B$ is meager.

> $\mathbf{Def}$. Let $X$ be a topological space. A set $A\subseteq X$ has the Baire property ($BP$) if $A=^* U$ for some open set $U\subseteq X$.

I have three questions regarding the proof of the following proposition:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. The class of sets having the $BP$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on X. It is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets and all meager sets.

1. In the first line of the proof we are showing that given an open set $U$, then $U\triangle \bar{U}=\bar{U}\setminus U=\bar{U}\setminus U^{\mathrm{o}}=\partial U$ is meager since the boundary of an open set is nowhere dense. Then $U=^* \bar{U}$. I think that I can't conclude that $U$ has the $BP$ from here because actually $\bar{U}$ is not an open set, while I can conclude that if $F$ is a closed set then it has the $BP$ because $F=^*F^{\mathrm{o}}$ and $F^{\mathrm{o}}$ is open.
   So we are showing that open sets have the $BP$ when we show that this property is closed under complements. Am I right? So what does the first line of the proof is actually showing?
2. Maybe this is trivial, but if $M$ is a meager set, then $M=^*\emptyset$ and so $M$ has the $BP$. Is this correct?
3. About the last part of the assertion

> If $A =^* U$, where $U$ is open, then $M = A\cup U$, $M$ is meager, and $A = M\triangle U$.

So if $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all open and meager sets and $A$ has the $BP$ then $A=M\triangle U\subseteq M \cup U\in \mathcal{F}$. Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

[A.Kechris - Classical descriptive set theory, p. 47](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObHJn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An open set $U$ trivially has the BP, because $U =^\ast U$ as $U \triangle U = \emptyset$ is nowhere dense and meagre.

But that's not what the proof does: it needs as a mini-lemma that $U =^\ast \overline{U}$ for $U$ open and dually $F =^\ast \operatorname{int}(F)$ for $F$ closed for the proof of closedness of BP-sets under complement: If $A =^\ast U$, $U$ open then $X\setminus A =^\ast X\setminus U =^\ast \operatorname{int}(X\setminus U)$ by this mini-lemma applied to the closed $X\setminus U$. And $X\setminus A =^\ast \operatorname{int}(X\setminus U)$ shows $X\setminus A$ has the BP.

So that paragraph (after the simple observation about countable unions, which works as the meagre sets form a $\sigma$-ideal) shows finally the first statement of the proposition: BP sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

So BP is *one* of the $\sigma$-algebras containing all open sets and all meagre sets (by the observation in the first line above and your observation that taking $U=\emptyset$ we see all meagre sets are BP too), and if $\mathcal{A}$ is another such $\sigma$-algebra and $A$ has BP, so $A = ^\ast U$ for some open set $U$ then $A \triangle U = M$ where $M$ is meagre and it follows that $U \triangle M = A$ by standard properties of the symmetric difference and $\sigma$-algebras are closed under $\triangle$ and $U,M \in \mathcal{A}$ by assumption so $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\text{BP} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ and we have the minimality. The inclusion $M \triangle U \subseteq M \cup U$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Side note: we could have defined BP equivalently as $A =^\ast U$ for some open set $U$ or $A =^\ast F$ for some closed set $F$. Then closedness under complementation would have been completely free. Matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely left out the part of the proof about closure under complements...
Not it's all more clear, except for one detail: we observe that if $U$ is open then $U=^* \bar{U}$ and if $F$ is closed then $F=^* F^{\mathrm{o}}$, but when we prove closure under complements actually we use only the result for closed sets, right?

Comment: @mimar yes, but the closed part has the same proof. We only use the closed part for complements.

Comment: Okay right, thanks a lot.
Ps: you say that $U\triangle U=A$, that's obviously a typo, it should be $M\triangle U=A$.

Comment: @mimar true I fixed the typo.